# how to get list of hashes in redis db using java?

Tags: java, redis, jedis, redis-cli, redisson

Is there any way to achieve and implemen this using java program.

Currently I am referring Redis website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that hard if you take a good look at the Redis API in detail.

```
Set<String> hashes = new HashSet<>();
RKeys keys = redisson.getKeys();
keys.getKeys().forEach(key -> {
    if (RType.MAP.equals(keys.getType(key))) {
        hashes.add(key);
    }
});
```

This is an example written using Redisson as client.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried using the jedis client .

The below syntax helped to get the list of hashes .

```
Scan 0 Match FolderName:* count  10000
```

Its working very well.

Comment: I don't know why people  downvoted this when its worked fine.